# Using OpenLDAP to proxy to an Novell eDirectory LDAP Server

Tags: proxy, ldap, openldap, novell, edirectory

I'm currently trying to use OpenLDAP as a proxy to a Novell LDAP server and running in to a few problems. It seems that only certain objects are coming through and there's almost no hierarchy. (I can set a base DN and view a particular object... but if I set the real base DN... I can only see it... and no children.) My suspicion is that I need to find a Novell/eDirectory/DNS schema to use in OpenLDAP. Does anyone know where I can find one? I saw a few LDIF files in the schema directory, and I believe I can get an LDIF copy from eDirectory but I only see .schema files being used in the config. The slapd.conf file is below... thanks for any help or suggestions. Please let me know if any further information would be helpful

include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema

pidfile         /usr/local/var/run/slapd.pid
argsfile        /usr/local/var/run/slapd.args

database ldap

uri ldap://10.10.1.27:389/

binddn "cn=adminuser,ou=office,o=au"
bindpw "password"

suffix "o=au"

idassert-bind mode=self

access to *
        by * read

Answer (score 3):

Since you are having issues with eDirectory, you are quite lucky, since you can use [DSTrace](http://www.novell.com/communities/node/4418/the-many-faces-dstrace) with the LDAP option on to see what is going on, from the eDirectory server view.

Once you know what is being asked, and what the server is responding you can effectively troubleshoot the issue.

Basic eDirectory schema is complaint with LDAP and any standard LDAP schema should work for the most part.  To get some specific features you might need some additional support, but that does not sound like your issue.

If you have access to the 10.10.1.27 box, try and look at it via http://10.10.1.27:8008 (or possibly port 8010, or 8028 depending if you are running eDirectory on Netware, Windows or a Unix variant respectively).  This should redirect you to an https:// connection one port number higher (8009, 8010, or 8030 (ya 2 not 1)).  Look for iMonitor or Dstrace, and then clear all the other flags, and enable the LDAP flag.  Then the Dstrace Live icon will refresh on each click with the latest transactions.

Now as to your issue of:

> there's almost no hierarchy. (I can
>   set a base DN and view a particular
>   object... but if I set the real base
>   DN... I can only see it... and no
>   children.)

I would suspect this issue is more about not doing the right kind of query.  Sounds like you are doing Entry not Subtree queries.  This will be very obvious in Dstrace, as you will see a query event that looks something like:

```
10:19:01 B68BEBA0 LDAP: (10.1.1.42:55133)(0x0002:0x63) Search request:
base: "ou=people,o=acme,dc=com"
scope:2 dereference:3 sizelimit:1 timelimit:0 attrsonly:0
filter: "(&(objectClass=inetorgperson)(acme7DigitName=gxc1234))"
no attributes
10:19:01 B68BEBA0 LDAP: (10.1.1.42:55133)(0x0002:0x63) Empty attribute list implies all user attributes
10:19:01 B68BEBA0 LDAP: (10.1.1.42:55133)(0x0002:0x63) Sending search result entry "cn=gxc1234,ou=UNK,ou=People,o=acme,dc=com" to connection 0xa07e6c0
```

There the scope: 2 tells you it is an entry search.  You want to see it do a subtree (0) level search in order to get what you are looking for.

You can read more about how I used this sort of tooling to debug the nonsense that [SAP's GRC web interface does for LDAP data retrieval](http://www.novell.com/communities/node/9625/troubleshooting-external-ldap-application-sap-grc).